# Package urls replaced by 2tvenom/cborencode

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I am working on an upgrade from Magento 2.3 to 2.4.3-p2. After a recent composer update of an extension a lot of repository URLs were replaced with random entries like the below.

```
`codeload.github.com/2tvenom/CBOREncode/legacy.zip/f846724ad842916061127d20da4fe4e129f7d4b8`
```

Anybody has any idea why this is happening? I have tried several options from the github issue, but nothing seems to work for me https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use composer 2 or rename vendor and composer.lock and run composer install

You might need to hard set versions in composer.json to stop any upgrades you don't want

Edit: Magento 2.4.2 + supports composer V2

Comment: Composer 2 isn't the way to go, as the official docs state that composer 1 is required 2.4.3-pX

Comment: @JELLEJ 2.4.3-p2 is composer 2 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3-p2/composer.lock#L13282

Comment: While yes, it may support it, the documentation should be updated in this case :)