# URL change for source and dist in composer.lock

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I have updated the magento version from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 so when i checked the composer.lock file so it changed the all URLs for github. Please help me on this why this issue occuer.

[image]

Comment: What is your composer version?

Comment: Composer version 1

Comment: did you check this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358468/package-urls-replaced-by-2tvenom-cborencode They suggest composer 2 version for Magento 2.4.3

Comment: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html